# Many to many relationship in RDBMS

Tags: sql

What will happen to a many to many relationship when you are going to implement it to a particular RDBMS?

And what are the things need to do, when this happens.

Thanks!

Comment: It will get implemented and then you will move on to the next task.  What is your actual question?

Comment: I think clarification of the question would be nice. In short Nothing. It is just really poor design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an associative table to resolve many to many relationships in a RDBMS.

More info: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_entity

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new table(called bridge table generally) between the two tables which have many-to-many relationship. This bridge table will have foreign keys for both table.